# Как стилизовать value внутри input?

Tags: css, input

Всем привет.
Есть дизайн инпута, в котором value стилизуется таким образом ( см. скрин ).
Как такое можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0):

Держите

```html
    <div class="my_div">
        <input class="my_input" value="12334" name="name">
    </div>
    <style>
        .my_div{
            border: 2px solid #d2d5d9;
            padding: 2px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .my_input{
            background: #c3d5f6;
            color: #3874e0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 2px;
            line-height: 24px;
            margin: 0;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    </style>
```